# Why is my Windows 8 pc always powered on by moving mouse?

Tags: windows-8

I recently installed Windows 8 RTM, but found a very annoying thing. My PC always powered on automatically even in midnight. Eventually I noticed that I can power on the PC by pressing keyboard or mouse, and even moving mouse.

After searched this in Google, I turned off Sleep and Hibernate in Power Options -> System Settings -> Shutdown settings, but it still did not work.

Would anyone please help me?  I don't want to suffer from the noise of PC powering on in midnight any more.

Comment: Please do not include the answer into your question, I will fix this for you ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

1. Control Panel > Mouse > Hardware > Properties > Change Settings > Power Management and uncheck "Allow this device to wake the computer".
2. Control Panel > Keyboard > Hardware > Properties > Change Settings > Power Management and uncheck "Allow this device to wake the computer".

Answer (score 1):

This is @juggler's answer but updated for Windows 10.

In file explorer, copy this into the address bar `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers` and then press enter. Right click on the mouse and go to mouse settings. Hardware | Properties | Change Settings | Power Management | uncheck "Allow this device to wake the computer"

You may also see a "Keyboard settings" option in the mouse menu, if so you need to uncheck the same setting for the keyboard settings.