# Mouse turns PC on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot, mouse

[Why is my Windows 8 pc always powered on by moving mouse?](https://superuser.com/questions/468859/why-is-my-windows-8-pc-always-powered-on-by-moving-mouse/468875#468875?newreg=ab27069e69604158b709db16d7870037)
same problem but cant find power management tab in the settings.

Comment: If your question is about the missing Power Management tab in Window 8, then please make your question about that, and share your research.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 was intended to be a mobile operating system, The mouse movement could be because of when u touch the screen it detects as mouse movement.

check out this link:
https://superuser.com/users/23133/%c6%ac%e1%b4%87c%ca%9c%ce%b9%e1%b4%87007